# Is inflation the cause or just the consequence?

Tags: inflation, economic-growth, money, policy, recession

Inflation is usually referred as an issue to the economy and we analyze its consequences on income and economic growth.

My undestanding however is that the real issue is the negative shift in aggregate supply curve (Loss in productivity). Inflation is the consequence. Not the cause.

What is your opinion regarding this?

Comment: Welcome to economics.se questions that seek opinions are off topic on this site.